# How to remove the top, bottom, left... region when theming a node in Drupal 6

Tags: nodes, theming

After some revise on the template.php, I can theme a node with specific content type. However, could I remove the default region such as header, footer to make it likes a blank page?

Answer (score 2):

I think You need to create specific page.tpl.php for your content and don't include these regions in the template. You name them page--YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE_MACHINE_NAME.tpl.php according to [this thread](http://drupal.org/node/1035656). You can also try [this](http://drupal.org/project/node_page) module